# I deploy a Nextjs project in EC2 Ubuntu but when I close my SSH My Project Stop running in Elastic-IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, next.js

I upload a Nextjs project in ec2 Ubuntu and use command `npm start` after installing Node.js 14.19.0

[image]

Now my project is running fine, but when I close my putty suddenly my project goes down (stop working in elastic IP)

How can I keep my app running after closing the SSH connection?

[inbound traffic for port 3000 also open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0zR.png)

[I connect Instance from here as well as I can connect on putty with EIP and PPK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpxNd.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're saying that you SSH to the web server, you run `npm start` to start your webapp, and then you close the SSH session window. That kills whatever you were running, of course.

If you want the webapp to keep running then you need to run it properly as a service or background process, not as a foreground process. For example using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/).

Comment: What does "port 3000 got busy" mean? If the port is already in use then I would guess that you previously started the same app, or another one, listening on the same port. If so, kill that application. If not and another app is legitimately on port 3000, then choose a different port for your app.

Comment: The app should listen on 0.0.0.0:port and the EC2 instance's security group should allow inbound traffic to that port from the client you are using to test this.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0zR.png

Comment: From your test client, are you able to SSH to the EC2 instance using its EIP or are you able to ping the instance using its EIP (assuming you allow inbound ICMP)? Is your client on a corporate network that disallows certain outbound ports, for example anything but 22, 53, 80, 443)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpxNd.png
I connected from here with ubuntu instance and clone from git
then run my project...
project run on my Elastic IP:3000
but when I close my ssh or Instance whatever 
it stop my projest running on Elastic IP:3000